# Translated sentences of Kellerman's 'A complete grammar of Esperanto'

Tags: translation, books

At the end of lessons in Kellerman's 'A complete grammar of Esperanto' there are 'Sentences for Translation' exercises. Does anyone have a document with each lesson's translated sentences in Esperanto that I can use to verify my translations while practicing?

Comment: I found a link on Project Gutenberg, but no answers: https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/7787

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the following partial solution set by Vaughn Seward: [ANSWER KEY (PDF)](http://esperanto-edmonton.wdfiles.com/local--files/kellerman-answerkey/ACGOE_Kellerman_AnswerKey.pdf)

Unfortunately it only goes up to Lesson 17 (out of about 60).

I also found an online Hebrew version of the book which uses many of the same exercises, and includes solutions: [HEBREW TRANSLATION](https://he.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A0%D7%98%D7%95/%D7%94%D7%93%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A7_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%9D)

It contains all sixty lessons, but the sentences are differently numbered, and some are different altogether. I also noticed a typo or two.

Answer (score 2):

Vaughn H. Seward wrote the incomplete answer key, but he did not trust himself, and so he let his work be reviewed, proofed, and annotated by Dan Campbell. I have tracked down a couple instances on the web of a Vaughn Seward who has cross-connections to Esperanto, and I believe that he is an older gentlemen with gray hair and gray facial hair, well trimmed, and he seems to be healthy. He wrote a note on the last page of his answer key, dated 05-27-2008, where he says that the answer key will be completed later. I have not been able to find an email address. I take exception to some of his answers in small parts, but the answer key is nonetheless helpful, and I would like to see it finished. I will continue looking for contact information for either or both Vaughn H. Seward and Dan Campbell. I was happy to see that this interested others as well. I think its a good book, and I am going to try to work through it daily to the end.

Answer (score 2):

I happened to come across this discussion by accident. I'm pleased that there is still interest in the Kellerman book and the answer key that I had worked on back in 2007/2008. At the time, I was a beginner and, as you mentioned, I relied on more experienced members of our local club (namely Dan Campbell) to check the answers. I think it is a worthy effort to complete the answer key which I will add to my current task list.

I just checked, and I had actually completed up to chapter 47 out of the total of 60 chapters, so I'll need to finish the other 13. However, I'll need to first review and correct chapters 18-47 that wasn't part of what I had previously provided publicly.

Ray, can you provide the questions that you have some disagreemant, and perhaps can sort out what they should be.

Answer (score 1):

Update (2023-04-23): I have updated the Kellerman answer key. It now includes answers for chapters up to chapter 38.

Answer (score 1):

Update (2023-10-04): We have completed all 60 chapters of the Kellerman answer key, and have updated our website. We have also corrected a few things in the colour version of the Kellerman text.

http://esperanto-edmonton.wikidot.com/kellerman-answerkey

Comment: This is great and much appreciated, thank you for doing this.